# Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new

Tags: vim

i dont know why this dont work, source % works fine but when i type :PluginInstall the error pop up
"Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new"
and this too "No bundles were selected for operation"

```
syntax on


set nocompatible          
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim

set noerrorbells
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set smartindent
set nu
set nowrap
set smartcase
set noswapfile
set nobackup
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set undofile
set incsearch

set colorcolumn=80
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=0 guibg=lightgrey

call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/vundle'
Plugin 'morhetz/gruvbox'
plugin 'jremmen/vim-ripgrep'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'vim-utils/vim-man'
Plugin 'git@github.com:kien/ctrlp.vim.git'
Plugin 'git@github.com:Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git'
Plugin 'mbill/undotree' 

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: What os are you using? how did you install the vundle plugin? are you using bash or zsh?

Comment: oh im using windows and install gvim and i installed vundle btw thanks for helping

Comment: Add the following to your .vimrc file: `set shell=/bin/bash` and check if solves your issue.

Comment: oh wow it worked thanks soooooo much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following line to your .vimrc

```
set shell=/bin/bash
```

There is a closed [issue](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/690) which describes error similar to yours.

In installation [guide](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/#quick-start) you can see that `set shell=/bin/bash` is recommended to be used in `fish shell`.

> 5. (optional) For those using the fish shell: add set shell=/bin/bash to your .vimrc

You may not be using `fish` shell but that is solution recommended in the [issue](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/690).