# vim Error detected while processing function <SNR>66_MRU_Select_File_Cmd

Tags: vim

I use vim8. When I use vim, whether I open or save a file, there will be errors. To save a file, I must use: w!, Open the file must be q to close the error.

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>66_MRU_Select_File_Cmd[21]..<SNR>66_MRU_Window_Edit_File[67]..BufRead Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>25_Detect[17]..<SNR>25_BufInit[1]..<SNR>25_autoload[2]..script /root/.vim/bundle/vim-rails/autoload/rails.vim[169]..function <SNR>87_add_methods[2]..<SNR>87_function:
```

I tried to reinstall vim, but it didn't work

```
sudo apt remove vim
sudo apt install vim
```

Also try to modify the .vimrc file and copy the .vimrc file of vim that is normally used on other servers, but it doesn't work

I also tried to add the content shown in the answer [here](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1925) to the top of the file, but it still failed https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1925

```
if has('python3')
  silent! python3 1
endif
```

and i tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354810/error-detected-while-processing-function-vundleinstallernew), but it still failed [Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354810/error-detected-while-processing-function-vundleinstallernew)

```
 set shell=/bin/bash
```

Then I tried the solution [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3117), but it still didn't work https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3117

```
mv ~/.vimrc ~/.vimrc_back
mv ~/.vim ~/.vim_back
git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
cp ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/test/minirc.vim ~/.vimrc
```

What should I do so that vim can be used normally and no error will be reported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a script is sourced by Vim it is given a number, which can be used to make sense of a stack trace like yours (edited for legibility):

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>66_MRU_Select_File_Cmd[21]
..<SNR>66_MRU_Window_Edit_File[67]
..BufRead Autocommands for "*"
..function <SNR>25_Detect[17]
..<SNR>25_BufInit[1]
..<SNR>25_autoload[2]
..script /root/.vim/bundle/vim-rails/autoload/rails.vim[169]
..function <SNR>87_add_methods[2]
..<SNR>87_function:
```

Before reinstalling Vim, a more constructive approach would be to figure out whether the problem occurs in Vim's own runtime files or in *yours*. You can use `:help :scriptnames` to put a filename to those numbers, so to speak.

Without even seeing the output of that command, it doesn't take much effort to find out that at least *some* of your problems come from *your* runtime files:

```
" one plugin
<SNR>66_MRU_Select_File_Cmd[21]
<SNR>66_MRU_Window_Edit_File[67]

" another plugin
..script /root/.vim/bundle/vim-rails/autoload/rails.vim[169]
..function <SNR>87_add_methods[2]
..<SNR>87_function:
```

Which means that you should look for the actual cause, not throw the towel and reinstall Vim or try random answers to random unrelated questions.

One good starting point would be line 21 of function `MRU_Select_File_Cmd()` in script number 66, which should be a call to `MRU_Window_Edit_File()` in your outdated version. The stack trace then points to line 67 of that function, and so on.

Hypotheses:

- badly installed plugins,
- incompatible Vim version,
- incompatible plugins,
- options incompatible with your plugins,
- etc.

Good luck.